# How to flash a tag in HTML indefinitely using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

In a web page I'm writing a user plays a game, once they win, text is supposed to flash. Once the user hits restart the text flashes. I would like to know how I can use Jquery(I have to use jquery as a requirement) to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a snippet that I believe exhibits the requirements you're looking for.

This depends on `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to handle a a repeating callback that toggles a CSS class. You can use further css animations / transitions to spruce up the effect more.

```js
(function() {
  var flasherInterval = 0,
    $flasher = $('#flasher');

  $('#win').on('click', function() {
    if (!flasherInterval) {
      flasherInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $flasher.toggleClass('hidden');
      }, 250);
    }
  });

  $('#restart').on('click', function() {
    console.log(flasherInterval);
    clearInterval(flasherInterval);
    if (!$flasher.hasClass('hidden')) {
      $flasher.toggleClass('hidden');
    }
    flasherInterval = 0;
  });
}());
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="win">Win</button>
<button id="restart">Restart</button>

<p id="flasher" class="hidden">Flashing text!</p>
```

Comment: I would not use this code as-is with out any modifications ,  if in this case clicking the "Win" button more than once after the text is flashing unexpected results will happen and clicking restart will not stop the flashing .  But again , these answers are meant to push you in the right direction , not fully write out complete code you you  @Miguel

Comment: I didn't catch that I would blow away the old interval ID, nice catch. @ScottSelby I updated per your comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
 // loop showing and hiding for 1.5 seconds
   while(blink){
     setTimeout(function(){ $('#myDiv').hide() , 1500);
     setTimeout(function(){ $('#myDiv').show() , 1500);
   }
});
```

don't actually use this code  - it's pretty bad , and meant to get you started ...  just an idea - this shows for to set a delay , how to show and hide

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the blink plugin.  http://antiyes.com/2009/08/24/jquery-blink-plugin/